# How to load custom php file in Wordpress themes

Tags: theme-development

I'm just created a website using wordpress and a custom theme for it.
This is my theme directory

```
/themes/customtheme/
 -index.php
 -header.php
 -footer.php
 -blog.php
 ....
```

The index.php includes header,footer,information to shown on my website, and a link to my blog page.

Blog file will looks same ask normal blog site.

may i know how to wite a hyperlink(a href) in index.php under theme directory so that it can prompt to the blog.php when click?
Blog

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create custom php file to do that. Basically, Wordpress is for blogging.
You just have to create a Category named Blog and create some post under Blog category and in your folder theme just create category.php to show all your post.
I suggest you to have a look Wordpress Template Hierarchy. It helps you to build a custom theme for Wordpress.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: May i know to to link between theme file IF my index.php is all my blog posts, and i need a link to this index.php from a home.php(which is the main page of the website). e.g a href="", www.mysite.com/blog for blog post page

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to make. But for create a category link you can use get_term_link('blog', 'category'). And to display all blog post in index.php I usually use get_posts function. Here is the documentation https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts.